# TypeError when using pandas DataFrame.idxmax()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code (using pandas, pandas_datareader)

```
info = robinhood.RobinhoodHistoricalReader("AAPL", start=start, end=end, interval="5minute", span="day")
prices = pd.DataFrame(info.read(), columns=['close_price'])
minutes = prices.idxmax(axis=0) * 5
```

Gives a TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Any idea how to fix this? I just want to find the index of the max price in my dataset.

Comment: Could you give information about the column types? Try `prices.dtypes`. There is a good chance that a column is of string type while you expect float type.

Comment: Apparently they're type float, since dtypes says it's float64

Comment: Plus, prices.max() works without a TypeError.

Comment: Is your first column (The dates) defined as the index? If not, it will try to find the maximum index for all the columns, including the date column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
info = robinhood.RobinhoodHistoricalReader("AAPL", start=start, end=end, interval="5minute", span="day")
prices = pd.DataFrame(info.read(), columns=['close_price'])
minutes = prices.astype(float).idxmax(axis=0) * 5
```

Assumes your row index is numeric. `minutes` is now a row showing the row_index*5 for the max cell value in each column.